# keep duplicate row in kendo grid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a requirement where I need to keep row which can be repeated.
The requirement is I am dragging value from one grid to another grid.
but When I remove a row it will remove all rows which are same

I am using kendo `remove` function e.g.

```
rightGrid.dataSource.remove(sortElement);
```

if I drag a row which is duplicated, it removes all same rows not that only one.

Is there any function which can remove only that particular row.

I have also used `removeRow` but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Grid's removeRow():

```
$("#grid").on("click", "button.remove", function() {
    var $tr = $(this).closest("tr"),
        grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");

    grid.removeRow($tr);
});
```

Or You can use DataSource's remove():

```
$("#grid").on("click", "button.remove", function() {
    var $tr = $(this).closest("tr"),
        grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid"),
        dataItem = grid.dataItem($tr);

    grid.dataSource.remove(dataItem);
});
```

You can also check the [demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/EkuTab/2) from telerik

To remove the duplicates , you can use the following

```
function onSave(e){
var currentProductName = e.model.ProductName;
var currentProductID = e.model.ProductID;
var data = this.dataSource.data();
for(item in data){
if(data[item].ProductName == currentProductName &&
data[item].ProductID != currentProductID){
e.preventDefault();
alert("Duplicates found");
// here you can delete your Duplicates
// you had to pass ur UID to 'getByUid' function
// var dataRow = $('#grid').data("kendoGrid").dataSource.getByUid(uid);
// $('#grid').data("kendoGrid").dataSource.remove(dataRow);
}

}
}
```

Comment: I don't want to remove duplicate rows that's the main concern. in your demo when you check both rows has diff. data-uid. In my case there are same because that row is from another grid.